# three.js cube: wires show over textures on Safari and Firefox, not Chrome

Tags: three.js, cube

I'm just a 3D newbie, and this is my first experiment with Three.js:

http://www.miguelrivero.net/mainWeb/images/portafolio/exp/BowieNextDay/heroesCoverCube.html

Any idea why the side textures show these wires?

Thanks!

Comment: Note: you are using a version of three.js that is 2 years old. Consider updating to the current version r.59.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably using the canvas renderer. Although you seem to try to use WebGL, it falls back to Canvas. Try to update for more recent version first.

CanvasRenderer has this wireframe behaviour. To work around it, you can set `material.overdraw` to true. In r59 this parameter was changed from boolean to number.

WebGLRenderer should not have this problem, if you manage to get this to work.